# Find out the reason that the Styles and scripts in the theme are loading properly in localhost but Not in server after deploying

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

My custom theme works well on my localhost, but when I upload it to my domain, it can not enqueue any of my styles and javascript. I have everything done correctly.

wp_head & wp_footer installed, wp_enqueue_script & wp_enqueue_style defined for each element.

**Functions.php**

```
function load_stylesheets() {

    wp_register_style('bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

     wp_register_style('font', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('font');

     wp_register_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/animate.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('animate');

     wp_register_style('owl', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/owl.carousel.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('owl');

     wp_register_style('theme', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/owl.theme.default.min.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme');

    wp_register_style('tooplate', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/tooplate-style.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('tooplate');

    wp_register_style('stylesolo', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/stylesolo.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('stylesolo');

    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css', array(), 1, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');

    wp_register_style('datepicker', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('datepicker');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_stylesheets');


function addjs() {

     wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
     wp_register_script('popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('popper');
     wp_register_script('bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
     wp_register_script('sticky', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.sticky.js', array(),  1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('sticky');
     wp_register_script('stellar', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.stellar.min.js', array(),  1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('stellar');
     wp_register_script('wow', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/wow.min.js', array(),  1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('wow');
     wp_register_script('smoothscroll', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/smoothscroll.js', array(),  1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('smoothscroll');
     wp_register_script('owl', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array(),  1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script('owl');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'customjsjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/customjs.js', array( 'jquery'), '1.0.0', true );    
    wp_localize_script( 'customjsjs', 'MBAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-form');

     wp_register_script('datepicker', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('datepicker');

        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'custom_js', 'ajax_object', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','addjs');
```

I do not know what i am doing wrong, i have looked up alot of solutions but seems like my code is correct. Can anyone tell me what might be the problem.

Comment: Is it a child theme? In which case you should you  get_stylesheet_directory_uri rather than get_template_direcrtor_uri. Just a thought.

Comment: I changed the get_stylesheet_directory_uri still nothing. On Monday my original code was working then it stopped working after uninstalling the WordPress and reinstalled it again. I've changed file permissions, I've contacted my server nothing! Now I see a 403 forbidden error. I changed permissions on folders and files but nothing

Comment: When you say uninstall wordpress what did you do? Reinstalling should be easy enough, download new wordpress, modify wp_config.php with db settings. It should run. Install parent theme & plugins and then install child theme. I can't explain the 403 error unless the files are owned by the wrong user, such as root for example. I'll do my best to help you get it back to where it was.